# How can I stop Access from displaying #DELETED after a record update?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have an access 2016 database pointing to a MySQL backend.  I have a form with a subform.  The subform is in continuous form view.

I made a chance to the entry of the subform and now when my users tab through the creation of a record to the next record the record just created displays #Deleted in all the text box fields.  Hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> corrects the problem but it's an extra step I want to avoid.

Here is the code I added.

```
Private Sub cboOperationNUM_AfterUpdate()

    If Nz(DLookup("[autoOut]", "[dataDetailOperations]", "[dataDetailOperations_NUM] = " & Me.cboOperationNUM.Value), "") = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf DLookup("[autoOut]", "[dataDetailOperations]", "[dataDetailOperations_NUM] = " & Me.cboOperationNUM.Value) = -1 Then
        Me.opOutsourcedPO.Value = 0
    Else
        Me.opOutsourcedPO.Value = Null
    End If

End Sub
```

[Video Capture of the problem](https://youtu.be/gz4jHOcVCyM)

If an Outsource Operation is select it enters a 0 into the PO field.  If not an outsourced operation it enters a NULL.  What I have found is if the PO field (int(5) in MySQL) is set to a number and then made blank (NULL in VBA or deleted from the form), when the record is updated it shows #Deleted until a refresh.  If I comment out the Else portion of my code everything seems to work but it doesn't empty the PO field if the operation is not outsources.  This is functionality I'd like to keep.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see a bunch of people making edits to my post.  Usually I avoid Stack Exchange because I tend to get yelled at for some rule violation every time I post.  Can you please let me know what I did wrong this time?  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to ask, check [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48449312/revisions) to see what people changed and learn form them.

Comment: Perhaps store the recordset bookmark value in a variable and reset the bookmark after your code. Otherwise you will likely have to get the PK of the record you were all and then reapply the select property on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Since you state that refreshing the form using <kbd>F5</kbd> solves the problem, you could add:

```
Me.Refresh
```

After

```
Me.opOutsourcedPO.Value = Null
```

This obviously doesn't solve the underlying problem, but may offer a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  Seems the only workaround right now is to remove Me.opOutsourcedPO.Value = Null.

Comment: You could also try `Me.Requery`

Comment: Both of these place the cursor back at the 1st field of the first record in the subform or main form depending on which I try to refresh/requery.   I also tried putting the refresh in AfterUpdate of the PO field.  Same undesirable result.  I appreciate the help.